# Question about using Zoom and Focus at the same time under CameraX

Tags: android, android-camerax

I would like to be able to zoom and focus my preview. Both types function separately from each other. However, they don't work together. The following code only zooms the image in the tab onto the screen but nothing is focused. If I remove the zoom block, the focus works. If I put the zoom block in the ACTION_DOWN function, only the focus works.

```
 val scaleGestureDetector = ScaleGestureDetector(this, listener)


 binding.previewImg.setOnTouchListener {_, motionEvent: MotionEvent ->

   //Zoom
   scaleGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(motionEvent)
   return@setOnTouchListener true


   when (motionEvent.action) {
         MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN -> {        
         return@setOnTouchListener true
        }
         //Focus
         MotionEvent.ACTION_UP -> {
          // Get the MeteringPointFactory from PreviewView
          val factory = binding.previewImg.getMeteringPointFactory()

           // Create a MeteringPoint from the tap coordinates
           val point = factory.createPoint(motionEvent.x, motionEvent.y)

          // Create a MeteringAction from the MeteringPoint, you can configure it to specify the metering mode
           val action = FocusMeteringAction.Builder(point).build()

          // Trigger the focus and metering. The method returns a ListenableFuture since the operation
          // is asynchronous. You can use it get notified when the focus is successful or if it fails.
          cameraControl.startFocusAndMetering(action)

          return@setOnTouchListener true
          }
            else -> return@setOnTouchListener false
         }

  }
```